how to set holdout role in mlr3
R version 4.4.0
    library(mlr3verse)
    library(mlr3learners)
    data("titanic", package = "mlr3data")
    task = as_task_classif(titanic, target = "survived", positive = "yes")
    task$set_row_roles(892:1309, "holdout")

error output
task_set_roles(private$.row_roles, rows, roles, add_to, remove_from):
Assertion on 'roles' failed: Must be a subset of {'use'}, but has additional elements {'holdout'}.

I can't run this line of code correctly
    task$set_row_roles(892:1309, "holdout")

addational  information about task
    task$row_roles

1 2 3 .... 1309 (including 892:1309)
$use
[1]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
  [19]   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
  [37]   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
  .....
 
 [937]  937  938  939  940  941  942  943  944  945  946  947  948  949  950  951  952  953  954
 [955]  955  956  957  958  959  960  961  962  963  964  965  966  967  968  969  970  971  972
 [973]  973  974  975  976  977  978  979  980  981  982  983  984  985  986  987  988  989  990
 [991]  991  992  993  994  995  996  997  998  999 1000
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 309 entries ]

